# What kind of action is it to throw an object when not making an attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The scenario is using darkness on a stone or playing card.  The caster wants to move the spell center without moving himself, so throws the object.

Dropping an item up to 5 feet away is a free action.  When targeting further distances, what kind of action is it, and what is the max range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, even if it's not exactly the same, I would resolve this as if it were a [splash weapon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Throw-Splash-Weapon) thrown at a grid intersection - in summary, it's a standard action, and the character makes a ranged attack against AC5. If they hit, it goes where they wanted. If the attack roll misses, it scatters a square away for each range increment away. I would use the range increment of an improvised weapon, so 10'.

A character could also potentially move to where they want the object, and then drop it as a free action.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74329/discussion-on-answer-by-yogozuno-what-kind-of-action-is-it-to-throw-an-object-wh).